# jQuery - Detect the div id automatically

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to automatically detect what div is clicked, and then add the text for a specific div.

So, here is what I'm trying to do:

```
$('#sjalland').live("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $('#searchBoxBig').val('Sjælland, ');
    $('#searchBoxBig').focus()

return false;
});
```

Now, I have 6 div's that has to activate this function (like #sjalland) when clicked. But right now it looks like I have to create 6 of the same function?

How do I create something smart to detect which div is clicked, instead of creating 6 of the same function and then replace #sjalland with #midtjylland, #nordjylland etc etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your divs the same class and use the classname as a selector instead of the id. e.g.

```
$(".someclassname").live("click", function() {
    $('#searchBoxBig').val($(this).attr("id")).focus();
});
```

Alternatively, apply the click callback to a containing div and use the `event.target` to detect which inner div was clicked (use `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent the event from bubbling up to the parent div).

Comment: This is great! Works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the action you can use $(this) to check for the specifically clicked item.

Example:

```
$("div.myDivs").click(
    function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id"); //Id of the object
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `e.target` to get the clicked on element (i.e. if you bind to the parent and want to know which child was clicked on).

Use `this` to get the element the handler was bound to.